# Corona sdk composer not found

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I tried to switch to using composer instead of storyboard in my new game. I haven't got very far because the following message

"module 'composer' not found:resource (composer.lu) does not exist in archive"

Anyone know what I could do?

Comment: Please show the code that you use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composer is only available right now (Feb 13, 2014) in the Daily Builds. If you're using the Starter (free) edition of Corona SDK you don't have Composer available. It will be available for Starter edition users in the next public release of the SDK (release date unknown).

Comment: @samhogan Please remember to upvote when you think an answer is useful (even for other peoples questions), and accept (check mark) the answer that was most useful.